# RE: singular matrix and eigenvectors

Tags: matrices

RE:  I can't understand this matrix

$\begin{pmatrix}-1&1/3&0&0\\1&-1&2/3&0\\0&2/3&-1&1\\0&0&1/3&-1 \end{pmatrix}$

It has determinant 0, rank 3 out of a possible 4, and yet it has four linearly independent eigenvectors.

$\begin{pmatrix} 1\\3\\3\\1\end{pmatrix}$,
$\begin{pmatrix} 1\\-1\\-1\\1\end{pmatrix}$,
$\begin{pmatrix} -1\\-1\\1\\1\end{pmatrix}$,$\begin{pmatrix} -1\\3\\-3\\1\end{pmatrix}$

These are linearly independent, so they form a complete basis.  I don't understand this.  I thought that a matrix with determinant zero should not have a set of eigenvectors that make a complete basis.   Where I am going wrong?  I realize the first eigenvector has eigenvalue 0.

Thanks so much.

ps  When I put these four eigenvectors into a matrix, it has rank 4, so I know they are linearly independent.

Comment: It's not a problem that these are independent. It only means that the matrix is diagonalizable, hence that $\mathbb R^4$ is decomposed into a direct sum $E_0\oplus E_\lambda\oplus E_\mu\oplus E_\kappa$, where $\kappa,\mu,\lambda$ are the non-zero eigenvalues.

Comment: Thanks.  But can a singular matrix (determinant 0) be diagonalizable?

Comment: I mean, 1) a singular matrix cannot be inverted, 2) a matrix that is diagonalizable can be inverted.  Where am I going wrong.

Comment: Yes sure, in the appropriate basis your matrix is $\begin{pmatrix}\kappa & 0 & 0 & 0\\0 & \mu & 0 & 0\\0 & 0 & \lambda & 0\\0 & 0 & 0 & 0\end{pmatrix}$

Comment: So I guess my problem was thinking that being "diagonalizable" was the same as being "invertable".

Comment: You certainly know that invertible means that the determinant is non-zero (in $\mathbb R$ or $\mathbb C$), and that the determinant is the product of the eigenvalues. Hence invertible means *all eigenvalues are non-zero*, whereas diagonalizable doesn't really care about what the eigenvalues are.

Comment: the zero matrix is not invertible, and is diagonlizable

Answer (score 1):

As said in the comments,

It's not a problem that these are independent. It only means that the matrix is diagonalizable, hence that $\mathbb R^4$ is decomposed into a direct sum $E_0\oplus E_\lambda\oplus E_\mu\oplus E_\kappa$, where $\lambda,\mu,\kappa$ are the non-zero eigenvalues.
Hence in the appropriate basis, your matrix is

$$\begin{pmatrix}\kappa & 0 & 0 & 0\\0 & \mu & 0 & 0\\0 & 0 & \lambda & 0\\0 & 0 & 0 & 0\end{pmatrix}$$

which is still not invertible, but is diagonal.

Answer (score 1):

An $n\times n$ matrix $A$ is *diagonalizable* if $A$ has $n$ linearly independent eigenvectors.

An $n\times n$ matrix $A$ is *invertible* if there exists an $n\times n$ matrix $B$ such that $AB=I_n$.

There are diagonalizable matrices that are not invertible. For example, the zero-matrix is diagonalizable but not invertible.

There are also invertible matrices that are not diagonalizable. For example, let
$$
A=
I_n+S_n
$$
where
$$
[S_n]_{ij}=
\begin{cases}
0 & j\neq i+1 \\
1 & j= i+1
\end{cases}
$$
Then $A$ is invertible but not diagonalizable.

The two examples above demonstrate that **diagonalizability is unrelated to invertibility**.